# Optimum Weight of Auto Encoders

Tags: autoencoders

I'm completely a noob in auto-encoder and deep learning thing. And now I'm trying to implement a simpe auto-encoder.

What I want to ask is: If given same dataset, will auto encoder produce the same optimum weight?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It depends upon your weight initialization and your training algorithm. If you use the same initial weights each time, use a deterministic training algorithm, and do not change the order in which your training data is fed into your algorithm, then I believe you should come up with the same results.

Comment: @John Yetter I use L-BFGS for training. If I randomize the initial weight, then it's normal if i always get different weight, right? Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> It depends upon your weight initialization and your training
>   algorithm. If you use the same initial weights each time, use a
>   deterministic training algorithm, and do not change the order in which
>   your training data is fed into your algorithm, then I believe you
>   should come up with the same results. – John Yetter

(   I use L-BFGS for training. If I randomize the initial weight, then it's normal if i always get different weight, right? Thanks for your response – MCRmy   )